# Hyper-V dedicate network adapter to 1 VM

Tags: windows, routing, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I have one windows server, 2 network adapters, 2 public IPs and I want to route/port redirect each IP to one of VMs (so I can host on :80)

At the same time I want to partially use one of the IPs to connect remotely to the windows server (MSTSC)
It looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that windows can set only 1 adapter to share internet with the others (Adpater 1 is sharing internet with Virual Switch).

I would like to delegate or route the other adapter directly to the VM2. **How can I achieve that?** I cannot set the IP address .107 directly to the VM2 because it is already taken by adapter2 of the windows server.

Comment: Don't configure an IP address for adapter 2 on the hypervisor ("physical" server). Make a virtual switch in Hyper-V manager, connect it to an external network, select adapter 2, select that virtual switch in the settings for VM2, configure the IP address you want on the virtual adapter in VM2.

Comment: I already figgured out that I can create a internal virtual switch and then bridge Adapter 2 to the internal virtual switch. Do you see any problem with this solution?

Comment: Why not just make it an external switch? The whole point of an external virtual switch is to do exactly what you wrote you want to do in your question.

Comment: You don't mention what OS you're running Hyper-V on. If it isn't Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 then you can't do NAT with Hyper-V. Additionally, your question begs the question: Why are you not using a firewall/router in front of the Hyper-V host to do the NAT and port forwarding for you?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Because If i make it an external switch both the hosting windows server and the VM would need to have their own IPs, right?

Comment: @joeqwerty My bad, its Windows server 2014 R2. As for the router - I did not see much of a benefit of buying another HW. But its true that since I had to buy the switch anyway, it doesnt make much sense :)

Comment: I don't understand your last question. I thought you already had the host server taken care of and you are trying to dedicate a physical interface to one virtual machine. If that's the case, then the physical interface **should not have an IP assigned to it in the host server configuration pages**. Just connect an external vswitch to both the physical interface and the VM in question, and configure the desired IP address on the NIC properties page **inside the guest VM**.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by:

1. Removing the IP:107 from the physical network card on the host
2. Configuring the an External Hyper-V Switch and remove the check box from "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter"
3. Add the IP:107 directly to the VM network card.

[image]

I'd advice that you add a firewall if this is a real IP to protect your VMs.